# CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION BSoD on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

So this is a continuation of my misadventures [on this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1050684/driver-power-state-failure-bsods-on-windows-10-laptop-upgraded-from-8-1)...where I resolved some problems by updating my Nvidia driver. I updated my Intel graphics driver to a new beta version as I discussed on that question's comments, and turned of my laptop for the night but now this morning I had a BSoD with the titular error. :( The annoying thing is for some reason there is no dump generated in Minidump folder for this crash..is that normal for this particular error? Surely not, right? I guess if it happens again I might downgrade my driver version (Intel) again but, is there anything I could do to help diagnose the problem right now?

EDIT: I have only had this BSoD once so far...time will tell if it's going to be a recurring issue or not. I also downloaded this `SPTD` thing from [here](http://www.duplexsecure.com/downloads) after seeing some advice for resolving this issue online but in hindsight that doesn't seem to make much sense afaict because it's not like I had some version of `SPTD` installed previously.

Comment: A dump file should be created.  This is a driver problem.  Does this crash happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I wasn't in safe mode when it happened, no. Do you think it would be likely to happen very quickly after booting in Safe Mode, if it was going to happen?

Comment: Without a dump file to analysis your asking for me to answer the impossible.

Comment: *sigh* that's unfortunate...I don't get why there is none for this crash...all the previous ones created a dump file. I guess when I have a chance I might leave my laptop running in safe mode for a while...and see if I get a crash, assuming it doesn't crash anyway in the meantime.