# Another DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE crash, first one in a while

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, hibernate

Ok to start off, for some extra context perhaps, I will say that I have asked a previous question on this site about this BSOD [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1050684/driver-power-state-failure-bsods-on-windows-10-laptop-upgraded-from-8-1). Thankfully I believe I have not seen my laptop crash at all again before today, ever since I updated drivers as described on the linked question. One thing that is probably rather important to note is that I hibernated my laptop for the first time in ages last night, and this BSOD happened perhaps at least an hour after powering it back up this afternoon. As I previously mentioned (at the least maybe in the reddit post my old question links to, not that you should feel obliged to read it) before I started getting this crash very often, without hibernating, I was getting it after "unhibernating" quite consistently and that stopped me from hibernating my laptop.

Consequently I feel the cause of this crash is strongly tied to hibernation. :/ TBH I would like to be able to safely hibernate my laptop again so I would be glad if someone could suggest a solution to this issue. Anyhow, without further ado here are some technical details to look through.

Simple bugcheck output

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffe0019b6a0840, ffffd00070ce3990, ffffe0019bbe99c0}

Implicit thread is now ffffe001`95ca6040
Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+5255d )

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Output of `!analyze -v`

```
    3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0019b6a0840, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd00070ce3990, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0019bbe99c0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffe001`95ca6040

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Alienware 14

SYSTEM_SKU:  Alienware 14

SYSTEM_VERSION:  A09

BIOS_VENDOR:  Alienware

BIOS_VERSION:  A09

BIOS_DATE:  04/23/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  07MJ2Y

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A01

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe0019b6a0840

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd00070ce3990

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe0019bbe99c0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  95ca6040

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 9be

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  ICY-ALIEN

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-26-2016 16:45:06.0892

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff802592d29ec to fffff8025942165d

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`70becbe0 fffff802`592d29ec : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x5255d
ffffd000`70becc10 fffff802`593e6c3d : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000000e 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiEndThreadAccountingPeriod+0xec
ffffd000`70becc40 fffff802`592d2796 : fffff802`5959b180 fffff802`5933d790 00000000`00000000 00000000`000000ff : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x17b3d
ffffd000`70becc70 fffff802`593c1c25 : ffffe001`9bd03bb0 fffff802`5959b180 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiGroupSchedulingGenerationEnd+0xb6
ffffd000`70beccb0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0x85


STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xffffe00195ca6040 ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  2f16e170ede2df1f2f71367e4ce0f1d269daa431

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  6500e784302654f495d2c05db6191015891f2f2a

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f08ac56120cad14894587db086f77ce277bfae84

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+5255d
fffff802`5942165d 448bc8          mov     r9d,eax

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  41c88b44

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+5255d

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56cd4410

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10586.162

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  5255d

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

TARGET_TIME:  2016-03-26T16:36:29.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-02-24 05:48:00

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160223-1728

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release_sec

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 1f77

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_nt!_??_::fnodobfm::_string_

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {4b556018-4707-5756-5581-83191182f054}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Then, as before I ran `!irp` with the `Arg4` value.

```
3: kd> !irp ffffe0019bbe99c0
Irp is active with 6 stacks 5 is current (= 0xffffe0019bbe9bb0)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0019b6dd040 00000000 fffff8025938e0b8-ffffe0019e535d60 Success Error Cancel pending
          Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys
 \Driver\nvlddmkm   nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000004 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe0019e535d60    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

So I noticed that like in the previous crash dump(s) the driver nvlddmkm.sys (which is Nvidia right?) is mentioned again. I am 99% sure I have not updated Nvidia driver since the time I switched to newest beta as discussed in comments of my last question..because I don't think a newer version exists yet. The beta version may have transitioned to being stable though because I don't think it's being marked as beta in GeForce Experience anymore.
I don't think I have dumps from the time anymore but, I feel it's worth noting that this seems to be the same kind of crash that happened what was probably close to if not more than a month ago now (post-hibernation crashes that is..I realise now my older question here is only 17 days old atm but whatever idk), before I even swapped to beta Nvidia and Intel drivers. As much as I would like to post more command outputs here like in my previous question, in case they would help more, I really need to go out to meet someone in a few minutes, so I will link my dump file for this latest crash [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4amHnnQLIlvby1zdm8wazE1NU0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you used windbg to determine the cause of the crashes yet?

Comment: the !IRP command shows you that nvlddmkm.sys is the cause. so update the nVIDIA GPU driver.

Comment: Umm, I don't mean to come across as rude in saying this but these comments sound like you haven't read _all_ of what I posted. At the least andre's; like I said as you know from last question I updated to latest beta driver and that driver is no longer beta now. There is no newer driver (at the least for my GPU) on Nvidia's site. Also as I said in this question this issue happened in the past before I ever updated to beta drivers. It may have started after a certain new "stable" driver for the Nvidia GPU was installed but I would not know what version it started at if so. :/

Comment: @Ramhound, well...yes? That is how I got the info I posted. What other commands should I use to determine the cause if what I posted is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

While your driver may be the most current, it may also be corrupt.  I would completely remove the current driver and install a fresh copy of the newest driver available.  If that does not "fix" the problem I would try a much older driver and then run a video stress test.

Completely remove the current driver (or software) and install the newest driver available.  For instructions on how to do that Read all about updating drivers by my partner JMH3143 here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-hardware/updating-a-driver/a5e6345e-af9b-4099-bef0-8d22254aa1c1?tm=1436753520149

Try this free video stress test:  http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/
FurMark Setup:

- If you have more than one GPU, select Multi-GPU during setup
- In the Run mode box, select "Stability Test" and "Log GPU Temperature"
  Click "Go" to start the test
- Run the test until the GPU temperature maxes out - or until you start having problems (whichever comes first)
- Click "Quit" to exit